# Rails: accessing associated models with several degrees of separation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a beginner in rails, and I have a question about accessing one model from another model that is associated with several degrees of separation.

Let's say I have these models:

```
Account has_many Spies
Spy has many SpyRelationships and belongs to Account
SpyRelationship belongs to Listing and belongs to Spy
```

How would I set up the associations so that I could simply pull all the listings associated with a given Account (via its spies and spyrelationships)? What line of code would allow me to do so, after those associations are setup properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to access a listing through a spy?

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :spies
  has_many :listings, through: :spies
end

class Spy < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  has_many   :spy_relationships
  has_many   :listings, through: :spy_relationships
end

class SpyRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :listing
  belongs_to :spy
end

class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :spy_relationships
end
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Actually I am trying to access listings through the account....is that possible?

Comment: Great, thank you. Currently in my listing controller I have the following query....how could I adjust it so that it only pulls the Listings for the current_user ? 
      @listings = Listing.search(params[:query], page: params[:page])

Comment: @IsaacYerushalmi This sounds like an unrelated question. You should probably mark this question as done, and post a new question and be sure to show your model arrangement for `current_user` and how it relates to `Listing`

Comment: Ok thanks, I did so here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930789/rails-accessing-associated-objects-that-are-several-degrees-apart . Thanks for your help